# how to display all images from their siblings/ from same parent?

Tags: images, get-posts, children, pages

I need to know how to display all images from the current page siblings.

for eg. I got two parents (Hockey and football) with children.
In all this children I got one or several images attached (I've simply uploaded them through wordpress deafult uploader).
Now I want a page (called "All images from all teams" ) that display all images that are attached to their siblings / has the same parent as current.
AND if you click on let say a images taken from the "New York Rangers" page, you will be sent to that page.

**Hockey**

- Detroit Red Wings
- Toronto Maple Leafs
- New York Rangers
- *All images from all hockey teams*

**Football**

- Liverpool
- Arsenal
- Manchester United
- *All images from all football teams*

Help! Please!

My code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>   <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>   <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  <div class="big-img"> <?php echo do_shortcode('[portfolio_slideshow size=full navpos=disable trans=scrollHorz pagerstyle=bullets autoplay=true]'); ?> </div>     <div class="post-content"> <div class="left-nav">  <?php include "left-sidebar.php";?>  </div>  <div class="content">  <div class="post-title"> <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></div>  <?php the_content('read the entry &#187;'); ?> <?php the_tags( '<div class="main-meta"> Tags: ', ', ', '</div>'); ?> <?php echo do_shortcode('[portfolio_slideshow size=thumbnail carousel=false navpos=disable ]'); ?>  <div class="clear"></div> </div>   <?php endwhile; ?>  <?php next_posts_link('&laquo; old Posts') ?> <?php previous_posts_link('new Posts &raquo;') ?>  <?php else : ?>  Not Found  <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/searchform.php"); ?>   <?php endif; ?>  </div>  </div>  <div class="right-nav">  <?php include "right-sidebar.php";?>  </div>  <?php include "footer.php";?>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you already have, or where you are stuck on exactly? Am I right that you need a function where you retrieve the attachmentchildren of the pages that have the same parentpage as the current one?

Answer (score 0):

Nice to see Liverpool at the top there!

I'd go about this using a page template. Given that as far as I'm aware we only know the page names I'll add it in that way.

The process is this:

1. Loop through top level pages
2. Collect child pages as array
3. Loop through child pages
4. Loop through child attachments

   ```
   <?php

   /*
   Template Name: All images
   */

   get_header();

   // pages to loop through
   $sports = array( 'Hockey', 'Football' );

   // empty array where we collect teams
   $teams = array();

   // collect teams
   foreach( $sports as $sport ) {

       $page = get_page_by_title( $sport );

       $teams = array_merge(
                   get_children( array(
                       'post_parent' => $page->ID,
                       'numberposts' => -1,
                       'post_type' => 'page'
                   ) ),
                   $teams
               );

   }

   // you could do some custom sorting or randomisation of the order here

   // loop through teams
   foreach( $teams as &$team ) {

       // get image attachments for each team
       $images = get_children( array(
               'post_parent' => $team->ID,
               'numberposts' => -1,
               'post_type' => 'attachment',
               'post_mime_type' => 'image'
               ) );

       // output images
       foreach( $image as &$image ) {

           // link to team page
           echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $team->ID ) . '">';
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'medium' );
           echo '</a>';

       }

   }

   get_sidebar();

   get_footer();
   ```

You'll want to modify the markup a bit and bear in mind this will be quite slow so you may want to consider a caching plugin.

Comment: If you want to display the portfolio slideshow thing for each team you can use the `do_shortcode()` snippets from your code in the teams loop rather than looping over the images. I'm assuming the shortcode will loop through the images for you